# Good example on if internet connection exists by using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I click a button I want to show or keep a hidden button hidden depending on whether the device has an internet connection or not. I have googled some but haven't found any really good example yet, do you know of any?

I want something like

```
$('#btnPrepareSynch').click(function () {
 checkConnection();
});

function checkConnection()
{
     if(connection exist) {
          $('#btnSync').show("slow");
     } else {
          $('#btnSync').hide();
     }
}
```

Possible?

Thanks in advance

Edit, it's ok to check if it has a connection by sending a ping to google.com or something

edit2:
with

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    cache: false,
    success: $('#btnSaveBottom').show("slow")
});
```

the button is shown even if I don't have any internet connection. If I change it to .hide() the button remains hidden. How do I add a fail statement here?

Answer (score 0):

The "error" callback is run upon any non-200 response from the server (or timeout.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://yourdomain.com/am_i_up.html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) { 
        $('#btnSaveBottom').show("slow");
        return true;
    }
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert(textStatus); //this will be 'timeout'
    } 
});
```

Comment: it still shows the button even if I don't have internet connection, also on http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events it says that "error (Local Event)
This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can never have both an error and a success callback with a request)."

Comment: Check my updated answer, with proper syntax for the "success:" callback.

Comment: Unfortuneately it still shows the button even though I'm not online